# searching some string in c#

Tags: c#

How I can searching some strings in C#? Well, if I have string "James Bond" and I am searching for "James" or "james" it will returning true, but if I am searching for "jame" it will return false. How I can do that?
Maybe I need little specific. I need searching based on word which splitted by ' ' See above. If I am searching for jame it will return false. If I use contains when I search for jame it will also return true right?

Comment: your question is ambiguous. "How I can do that?" means what exactly? How can you make searching for "jame" return false or how can you make searching "jame" return true. Please re-ask your question.

Comment: I am already updated it. see my question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question this is what you would use.

```
    var ex = "James Bond".ToLower(); //normalize case
    bool contains = ex.Split(' ').Any( x => x == "jame");
   //FALSE because the *word* "jame" is not found in "james bond"
```

Since this question is causing a lot of confusion, you have to keep in mind all of the casing involved.

```
var ex = "James Bond";
bool contains = ex.Contains("jame");
// FALSE because "jame" is not found in "James Bond" due to case-sensitivity

var ex = "James Bond".ToLower(); //normalize case
bool contains = ex.Contains("jame");
// TRUE because "jame" is FOUND in "james bond" due to normalized case
```

Comment: `contains` will be `false`

Comment: @Sahuagin that is what he desires

Comment: I thought he meant searching for `jame` giving `false` was a problem, but I think you're right. +1

Comment: at this point I have no idea what he meant, but I hope this can clear up some confusion. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `Regex` for this. You cannot use `Contains`, since it won't take into consideration case-insensitivity and match whole word pattern. Use this instead:

```
string text = "James bond";

// this will return true  
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\bjames\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// this will return false   
bool result = Regex.IsMatch(text, "\\bjame\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

In the `Regex` formats, the above `\b`s will match an alphanumeric-to-nonalphanumeric boundary (or vice-versa). In this case, this ensures that you will be matching `james` or `jame` as a whole word and not a partial word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Split` to separate a string into parts that are separated. Ex:

```
string[] items = "James Bond".Split(' ');
// items == { "James", "Bond" }
```

You can use `ToLower` to prevent case senstivity. Ex:

```
string lower = "James Bond".ToLower();
// lower == "james bond"
```

You can use `StartsWith` to determine if a string starts with some substring. Ex:

```
bool startsWithJame = "James Bond".StartsWith("Jame");
// startsWithJame == true
```

Using them all together:

```
bool anyWordStartsWith_jame_NoCaseSensitivity =
   "James Bond"
   .ToLower()
   .Split(' ')
   .Any(str => str.StartsWith("jame"));
// anyWordStartsWith_jame_NoCaseSensitivity == true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. For an example see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

here is is matching when "cow" is found anywhere inside the string. In your case it would be "Jame".

Comment: although this is correct, for such a trivial problem he is better off just using `Contains`

Comment: @KuyaJohn you're right he clarified his question. the question caused a lot of confusion due to the language used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Contains` method to search:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "joe", "bob", "chris" };
if(names.Contains("james")){
    //code
}
```

Comment: i think `Contains` doesn't really answers the question. if i have a string `Hello World` and i want to find the word `Hell` using `contains`, it will return true which the OP don't want. He wants to find the whole word just like what he have mentioned on the question.

Comment: as he mentioned,he wants to search a part of string for example "jame" not exactly "James" and in my case Contains is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Regular Expression using word boundaries. The following code will show you how you can match using a case-insensitive search and NOT have false positives with things like "jame". It works anywhere in a given string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name_to_match = "James Bond";
        string word_to_find = "james";
        string word_to_not_find = "jame";

        string patternToFind = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word_to_find);
        string patternToNotFind = string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word_to_not_find);

        Regex regexToFind = new Regex(patternToFind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Regex regexToNotFind = new Regex(patternToNotFind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        bool foundNameExpected = regexToFind.IsMatch(name_to_match);
        bool foundNameNotExpected = regexToNotFind.IsMatch(name_to_match);
    }
```

In this case, the boolean foundNameExpected will be true (because we expect "james" to match "James" in "James Bond"), however foundNameNotExpected will be false (because we do not want "jame" to match "James").

Answer (score -3):

Try this out.

Method:1

```
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox";
bool b;
bool c;
b = s1.Contains(s2);
c = s1.Contains("test")
```

bool b will return true. 
 
bool c will return false.

Method:2

```
    string str = "My Name is james";  

 int result = str.IndexOf("james");
```

result will be -1 if the particular word is not found in the sentence.

Comment: i think `Contains` doesn't really answers the question. if i have a string `Hello World` and i want to find the word `Hell` using `contains`, it will return true which the OP don't want. He wants to find the whole word just like what he have mentioned on the question.

Comment: @KuyaJohn We can fetch the expected result by using IndexOf("") method.

Comment: @Bala Ok.. and particularly why did you choose this answer for our communication.. Err.. :)

Comment: @Bala Ok i searched for you yesterday, but you were not available. where did you go yesterday?